# Hot water valve under kitchen sink

Tags: valve, kitchen-sink

Was going to replace kitchen faucet, I turned off cold water and removed the line to faucet, then turned off hot water valve but upon trying to remove the line to faucet, the hot water is still on and begins to spew when trying to remove line to faucet.

Comment: Maybe the valve isn't working, turn off the water supply to the hotwater tank?  Turn off the water to the house?

Comment: Please post photos of the valve and line.  A multi-turn shutoff valve relies on a washer to seal. Over the years, that rubber washer breaks down, especially on a hot water shutoff, leaving just pieces of the former washer, and it won't shut off any more.  If that's the case, you can rebuild the shutoff valve in place with a new washer.

Comment: PS - In the future you can turn on the faucet after you shut off the valve to (a) make sure the shutoff worked and (b) release any residual water pressure in the line you are about to disconnect.

Comment: When you replace the valves, use ball valves (also called quarter turn).  They are slightly more expensive but will last longer than you.

Comment: And your _question_ is? Please take the [tour] and note that this is a _Question_ & Answer site. It's hard to answer statements since they're not questions.